# meta keyboard key in Windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I use a Mac at office and a Windows OS at home, as it is common I am really getting confused with the use of two different Keymap shortcuts.
So I am trying to change my windows keyboard so to mimick an Ios keyboard.

Outside the specific use of a software as `hotkeys`to change the keyboard map, my problem is that the windows key is not recognized as meta.

According to different posts and the intelliJ blog/issue, I can make windows key as meta (mac os) adding in File `idea.proprieties` the string :

> keymap.windows.as.meta=true

Well does not work, when I put this string in IntelliJ and restart AS, meta is not recognized in fact if I try to change some shortcuts windows+ some letter, the IDE recognizes only that I pressed the hardware button `Windows, making impossible to use Mac OS keywords really useful and simple as Copy, Paste, Cut.

Comment: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-144702.

Comment: thank you but I was referring to that link as well, in fact The intelliJ employee Vassiliy Kudryashov suggests to set `keymap.windows.as.meta=true` but does not work for the reasons I quoted above, namely that the windows button+ a letter is not recognized in the intellij keymap, that means that windows is not recognized as meta I guess

Comment: There are comments about the same in this issue and the issue is still Open, following up in YouTrack is what you can do now.

Comment: thank you @CrazyCoder, happy to see that is an open issue and not some strange conflict I have it. Please consider in your backlog, that a lot of people would like to have one keyboard. Virtually every dev risk that goes in a new company, or have to use a different PC, and have to use the mouse/tracpad because of the keywords different. IntelliJ is smart, you know that developers want to use only the keyboard.